# Omemo Message Delivery Failed

Tags: java, kotlin, mongoose, xmpp, omemo

I'm facing this issue ,

```
 'org.whispersystems.libsignal.InvalidKeyException: Invalid signature on device key!'
 
 i tried it from conversations code
```

Non working Bundle is shared below -

```
<items](http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><items) node="eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.bundles:2041762935" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><item xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub" id="current">BWAgkeGro0tPZDgaHQvXm8F9t8/UHLtAoMs0GHfUxGRi6qR5aID1TPmGlXWz/+4pHzM9oQbFnD4vq1ByDp+fHkvbBObxqZj81QmrlXWQYd9j4SMnHeZFs2jOMZA3OuAgDg==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
```

when trying to process this bundle :-

```
final PreKeyBundle preKeyBundle = new PreKeyBundle(0, address.getDeviceId(),preKey.getPreKeyId(), preKey.getPreKey(),bundle.getSignedPreKeyId(), bundle.getSignedPreKey(),bundle.getSignedPreKeySignature(), bundle.getIdentityKey());
```

```
        try {
            SessionBuilder builder = new SessionBuilder(axolotlStore, address);
            builder.process(preKeyBundle);}
```

Internally this method gives me an error which is shown below -

```
public void process(PreKeyBundle preKey) throws InvalidKeyException, UntrustedIdentityException {synchronized (SessionCipher.SESSION_LOCK) {if (!identityKeyStore.isTrustedIdentity(remoteAddress, preKey.getIdentityKey(), IdentityKeyStore.Direction.SENDING)) {throw new UntrustedIdentityException(remoteAddress.getName(), preKey.getIdentityKey());}
```

// this exception I'm getting

```
if (preKey.getSignedPreKey() != null &&!Curve.verifySignature(preKey.getIdentityKey().getPublicKey(),preKey.getSignedPreKey().serialize(),preKey.getSignedPreKeySignature())){throw new InvalidKeyException("Invalid signature on device key!");}
```

what can be reason for it  , Can anyone help to guide us how we can resolve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem - message fails in one to one and multi party group chats. As soon as the message is sent, it immediately shows the error "delivery failed". With some users it is working but with few we are getting this problem

Our app is based on conversations as base code for android client and we are using OMEMO end to end encryption. Looking forward to some help from the community on getting this error solved.